# React & Bootstrap Classes & Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, styled-components, emotion, css-in-js

I want to be able to use Bootstrap's awesome utility classes like "d-flex", "btn-primary", "text-center", etc. together with Styled Components. Ideally do something like this we are able to do with Tailwind styled components:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'
import tw from 'twin.macro'

export const Wrapper = styled.div<{ extraTailwindClasses }>`
  ${tw`flex flex-col w-full mx-auto h-full`}
  ${p => p.extraTailwindClasses }
  color: red;
`
```

I want to pass the Bootstrap classes, and still have them minified in the HTML output. Is this possible?

Comment: With React + Vite + Typescript + Bootstrap 5, I have just this in main.tsx: `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`